# How to invoke this Angular method that's bound to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm inspecting the DOM on an Angular application and trying to figure out how I can reproduce one of the events that's bound to a button via the console. The button looks like this:

```
<button class="button tiny text player-add-button" ng-class="{ 'player-add-button': !player.inLineup, 'player-remove-button': player.inLineup }" ng-click="player.inLineup ? draft.rosterRemove(player) : draft.rosterAdd(player)">
```

What I'm trying to access here is `draft.rosterAdd()`. The problem is, this is a table, and there's multiple buttons and `player` is changing for every button. I'm not entirely sure how to define player here, even if I get into the scope of of the draft object, to pass it in as an argument to `rosterAdd()`

What's the best way to figure out how I can define `player` so that I can invoke `draft.rosterAdd(player)` for all of the players I want to add via the console?

Comment: Did you try to take a look at the source code and figure it out? Or is it minified?

Comment: It's minified unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in Chrome):

1. Right-click the desired button and select *Inspect element*;
2. Open the console tab (make sure the button markup remains selected);
3. Type `draft = angular.element($0).scope().draft`;
4. Type `player = angular.element($0).scope().player`.

Now you should be able to see how `player` is structured and call `draft.roasterAdd()` passing whatever you want.

Some useful references about the code above:

- [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)
- [Chrome's command line API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)

Comment: So this actually works. The problem is I need to get the entire player array in order to be able to retrieve the specific one I want to add programmatically.

Comment: @randombits I suspect there is an ng-repeat somewhere with a collection of players that you could gather that data from using the above suggestion. Probably something like `ng-repeat="player in players"`

Comment: @randombits Well, I can't help much more given the information you have provided. But now that you know how to inspect the scope of any element on the page, you should be able to figure out what you want.